# Подключение к БД в docker-контейнере из другого docker-контейнера

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, docker

Имеется Java приложение, работающее в контейнере Docker. Оно пытается подключиться к БД Postgres, которое так же работает в Docker-контейнере. Оба живут на одном сервере, и подключены к одной docker-сети, каждому контейнеру дано определённое имя.

`docker network inspect gitlabci`

```
[
    {
        "Name": "gitlabci",
        "Id": "2bef428d1ac728aa7e177c55716e2347eb70c6080a81ed63cfb48034acfc31da",
        "Created": "2022-11-15T16:31:04.474082241+03:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "152e59a27e70570d4f8ff8732742f0a8ad87226930bf14ffcef9932e0cc44ee8": {
                "Name": "auth-runner",
                "EndpointID": "580921d16d87e0939fa622197c55e98e207e4b6ea929dcea814470ed388a4f05",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "d1de071f33b7db58d456562b1eb113ce912d5c3e5d49886f074485d83edb301c": {
                "Name": "postgres-auth-db",
                "EndpointID": "f90b410948d2ec9380567d048bd37db3f91cc323366e42cdb802abefe89ddb2b",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Если зайти напрямую в контейнер с приложением `docker exec -it auth-runner bash`, и оттуда вызвать контейнер с БД `curl postgres-auth-db:5432`, то в ответ получаю `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`, что указывает на корректное соединение, но пустой ответ.

В Java приложении в файле *application.properties* для подключения прописана такая строчка: `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres-auth-db:5432/simpleauthdb`. К сожалению это не работает, и при сборке в maven на этапе тестов, при инициализации подключения к базе получаю ошибку `Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: postgres-auth-db`

Возможно я что-то делаю не верно, прошу помочь разобраться. В любом случае моя задача - указать приложению подключение к базе.

**P.S.** Если кто-то решит сказать, что не нужно кидать базу в контейнер и все дела - я в курсе. В моём случае это только болванка для корректного прохождения тестов.

---

**Дополнение, файл docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12
    container_name: postgres-auth-db
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - runner
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=simpleauth
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=simpleauthpassword
      - POSTGRES_DB=simpleauthdb
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  runner:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
    container_name: auth-runner
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /home/drunner/auth-runner:/etc/gitlab-runner:z
```

---

**Дополнение второе**
`/etc/nsswitch.conf`

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         files
group:          files
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Значит первым делом я беру настройки из файла hosts. Вот и он:
`/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.20.0.3      7e899edbaf1e
172.20.0.2      postgres-auth-db
```

Сеть поменялась по сравнению с началом вопроса, так как я перешёл от варианта самостоятельного создания сети docker к docker-compose.

Comment: Похоже что вы используете `default network bridge` - судя по документации (https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#connect-a-container-to-the-default-bridge-network), в этом случае можно соединиться с другим контейнером только по IP.  Попробуйте использовать IP адреса вместо имён или настройте сеть так чтобы можно было импользовать имена (https://docs.docker.com/network/)

Comment: Попробуйте подключиться по IP `172.18.0.2`, что получится?

Comment: @PakUula, это показалось мне хорошей идеей, но я получаю `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out`

Comment: странно это. Какими командами вы прикрепили контейнеры к сети? План Б - сделайте `docker-compose.yaml` и запустите ваши согласованно через `docker-compose up` или `docker compose up`

Comment: Более того, если зайти на контейнер напрямую - они условно видят друг друга. Сначала создал сеть `docker network create gitlabci`, после запускал контейнеры примерно так `docker run --name postgres-auth-db --net gitlabci -p 5432:5432 -d postgres:12`

Comment: @PakUula, попробовал docker-compose. Всё те же ошибки, ничего не поменялось. В дополнении к моему вопросу содержимое docker-compose.yml

Comment: Очень странно, в урле прописана БД db, в docker-compose DB: simpleauthdb, возможно нет базы(скрипты прописать или миграции), плюс у тебя твое апп должно depends_on на БД, а не наооборот.

Comment: @Charismatic, то, что не совпадают базы - это я тут накосячил, на деле всё одинаково и база есть. Тут тоже поправлю. А вот насчёт зависимости - благодарю. Надо попробовать!

Comment: И всё же это не работает. Я поправил docker-compose.yml, и получаю всё те же ошибки. Я залез в файлы `/etc/nsswitch.conf` и `/etc/hosts` контейнера. Что из этого получилось - во втором дополнении моего вопроса.

**Это всё ещё не работает!**

Comment: У тебя проблема только в том, что ты не можешь собрать Jar при билде? Или уже когда в контейнер собран, ты не можешь подключиться к бд ?

Comment: @Charismatic, в контейнере auth-runner живёт gitlab-runner,  который прогоняет pipeline GitLab CI. На данном этапе меня не интересует сборка jar-файла. Я хочу корректного прохождения тестов - в моём случае это `mvn test`. Однако тесты падают, так как дефолтный тест Spring - `contextLoads{}` не может инициализировать соединение с БД. 

Такая мелочь, но как заноза в известном месте!

Comment: Вот я поэтому и спрашиваю. На этапе тестов у тебя еще нет контейнера с бд, к которому он сможет подключиться. Так как и приложуха и БД у тебя в контейнере в одной сети, даже если ты запустишь отдельно БД в докере, то приложуха не сможет подключиться к БД, из-за того, что она вне нетворка докера. Тут советую использовать test_container, для теста БД. Другой случай, если ты уберешь нетворки, у тебя поменяется урл к БД на localhost, единственное, что могу посоветовать это test_containers, другого решения мне неизвестно.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `networks` в docker-compose.yml, см пример в https://github.com/gurock/testrail-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: @Charismatic, немного не согласен. auth-runner и postgres-auth-db поднимаются вместе. Сборка и тесты не начинаются сразу же. Они начинаются по моему действию в GitLab. Это по первой части. 

А вот насчёт второй - вопрос. Почему получается, что приложение поднятое в докере, не будет считаться с его сетью? Кажется в этом и есть вся загвоздка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем ничего не получилось и после двух дней тщетных попыток я решил не использовать БД в docker-контейнере.